# select using date from mysql timestamp mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have timestamp column called time in one of my table called tbl_recordings. Its storing data like 2019-04-10 19:51:08. Now I am trying to get result filtered by date but its not working with below query.

```
$date = 2019-04-10 

SELECT * FROM tbl_recordings WHERE time = $date;
```

here time is timestamp field in my table. Let me know if someone can help me for get out of it. Thanks

Comment: which data type is exaclty you time column  .. update you question and  add your table tbl_recordings  schema .. and show a sample for $date content  too

Comment: @scaisEdge I have edited it sir. Thanks

Comment: show also a $date content please

Comment: @scaisEdge I have added it sir!

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you $date value is a string you should compare the proper date converted  values

```
  SELECT * FROM tbl_recordings WHERE date(time)  = str_to_date($date, '%Y-%m-%d') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use date() as it will execute date() on all rows, even those which do not match

Try something like this

```
... WHERE date >='2019-04-10' AND date <'2019-04-11'
```